# How to download a specific labelled code from TFS using PowerShell Script?

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, powershell-5.0, tfs-2017

I have a PS script which downloads the latest code from TFS on my local machine but I want it to download a specific labelled code instead of latest.

Below is the script which downloads the latest code present in TFS,

```
$sourceLocation = "http://vwmaztfsapp:8080/tfs/MatchCollection"
  
$tfsCollectionUrl = New-Object System.URI($sourceLocation);  
  
$serverPath = "$/Match Web/Installscript Projects/Utility Scripts"  
  
#It gets copied at local path with the above folder sequence
$localPath = "C:\"

    
$visualStudiopath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer'
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
    Add-type -path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ProjectManagement.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.dll"


$tfsCollection = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection -ArgumentList $tfsCollectionUrl  

$VersionControl = $tfsCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])  
$latest = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionSpec]::Latest  
$recursionType = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType]::Full     
  
  
    try  
    {  
  
        foreach ($item in $VersionControl.GetItems($serverPath, $latest,$recursionType).Items)  
        {  
            $target =   [io.path]::Combine($localPath,$item.ServerItem.Substring(2))  
            $exists=[System.IO.Directory]::Exists($target)  
  
            if($item.ItemType -eq "Folder" -and !$exists)  
            {  
                New-Item $target -Type Directory  
            }  
            if($item.ItemType -eq "File")  
            {  
                $item.DownloadFile($target)  
            }  
        }  
        Write-Host "`n Successfully downloaded all the files to the target folder: " $localPath -ForegroundColor Green  
    }  
    catch  
    {  
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message  
        $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName  
        Break  
    }
```

I tried using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.LabelVersionSpec` but was not successful.
Can anyone please guide me to the correct link or script by which I can download the "$/Match Web" code using the label which I had applied on it. This is the label which I had applied on "$/Match Web" branch for e.g. - "PreBuildLabel-MatchEnterpriseBuild1"

@Assael Azran, getting below result in $vs

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (works for me):

```
$vs = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.LabelVersionSpec($label, $scope);
foreach ($item in $VersionControl.GetItems($serverPath, $vs,$recursionType).Items)  
{
  .....
}
```

$label - name of your label

$scope - The scope (project) of the label. To verify that through VisualStudio, navigate to **File-> Source control-> Find-> Find Label**.
In the "Find Label" form find your label and open it, then you will see the project name (the one under the collection), you can use it as the scope.

[LabelVersionSpec Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb132185(v=vs.120))

**UPDATE**

Upon request of @SRP, this is how you should create a branch from a TFS label:

```
$vcs = $server.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer]); 
$changesetId = $vcs.CreateBranch($sourceBranch, $destBranch,$vs)
```

[VersionControlServer.CreateBranch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff735147(v=vs.120))

Comment: The above code is giving me the below error in foreach for GetItems  :-                                                                                       Cannot find an overload for "GetItems" and the argument count: "3".
At C:\Suraj\POC PostGA\Label.ps1:37 char:19
+ ... h ($item in $VersionControl.GetItems($serverPath, $vs,$recursionType) ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: Are you getting any results to `$vs`? can you share what you did?

Comment: yes, I have added the screenshot of value above that is getting added. I simply added value to $label and $scope and copied the line in your answer $vs = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.LabelVersionSpec($label, $scope);

Comment: Which dll version of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client are you using? if you run `$VersionControl.GetItems($serverPath, $vs,$recursionType).Items` are you getting anything?

Comment: I am not sure, I completely understood your above query but i guess you want to know the values of the following variables present inside GetItems($serverPath, $vs,$recursionType). The $serverpath = "$/IntelliMatch Web/Release/NextGen_v20.2_GA", the value for $vs is already shared above in screenshot and $recursionType seems to be empty.  The Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client dll is of VS 2017 and it shows the file version as 15.129.28306.1  in its properties.

Comment: @ Assael Azran by bad, I missed this line from the script, "$recursionType = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType]::Full "      It is working now, thank you!!

Comment: @ Assael Azran instead of downloading the labelled code, if I want to create a new branch in TFS of the labelled branch is that possible? Where can I find the PS commands for the same, any link?

Comment: Thank you Assael Azran!!